# How to compare the value after fetchin it from properties file in JSTL

Tags: jsp, jstl

I am using  tag for localization please let me what am i doing wrong here 
`<fmt:message key="some.key" var="var1" />`
and checking condition like this
`<c:if test="${var1 == 1}"`
  `print some thing`
`</c:if>`

the value is not getting printed I mean it is not getting inside the if 
PS: I have tried `<c:if test="${var1 == '1'}"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That can have at least 3 causes:

1. `some.key` does *actually* not contain the value `1`.
2. You didn't declare JSTL format taglib by `<%@taglib%>`.
3. You didn't declare JSTL core taglib by `<%@taglib%>`.

To check the *actual* value of `some.key`, do so:

```xml
<fmt:message key="some.key" var="var1" />
<p>value of some.key is: ${var1}</p>
```

To ensure that JSTL format and core taglibs are properly declared, ensure that the following lines are present in top of the JSP file in question according the [JSTL taglib documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/):

```xml
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
```

To verify this, open the JSP page in webbrowser, do a rightclick and *View Source* to see the generated HTML output. You should see **no single piece** of JSTL/EL code.

Comment: @BaluC thanks what I did was i set a varable to 1 `<c:set var="var1" value="1">' then compared it in if, can we compare two string variable fetched from .properties file whic are holding numeric values by arsing them.

Comment: @BaluC could please answer this qn asked in this site by me "how to call parameterized method from JSP using JSTL"

Answer (score 1):

Another possible cause if that the fmt:message tag is outside the fmt:bundle tag  (or the fmt:bundle tag is missing entirely)

You should have something like this:

```
<fmt:bundle basename="path to resource bundle">
...
<fmt:message key="some.key" var="var1" />
....
</fmt:bundle>
```

You can also specify the bundle directly as an attribute of the fmt:message tag